# find available space in GB on all drive volumes in windows 2012 command line

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

How can I find the available space on all active drive volumes in GB on a windows 2012 server using the command line and /or powershell.

So far I tried this command, that fails:

```
wmic logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption
Invalid GET Expression.
```

Also tried this command but it gives the answer in bytes which is hard to interpret. Be great if I could get this to read out in GB:

```
PS C:\Users\us-tdunphy> wmic diskdrive list brief /format:list


Caption=AWS PVDISK SCSI Disk Device
DeviceID=\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
Model=AWS PVDISK SCSI Disk Device
Partitions=1
Size=268432012800


Caption=AWS PVDISK SCSI Disk Device
DeviceID=\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
Model=AWS PVDISK SCSI Disk Device
Partitions=1
Size=128849011200
```

I also tried this powershell command that gives and error:

```
PS C:\Users\us-tdunphy> powershell -command "& {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter 'DriveType = 3' |select PSComputerName, Caption,@{N='Capacity_GB'; E={[math]::Round(($_.Size / 1GB), 2)}},@{N='FreeSpace_GB'; E={[math]::Round(($_.FreeSpace / 1GB), 2)}},@{N='PercentUsed'; E={[math]::Round(((($_.Size - $_.FreeSpace) / $_.Size) * 100), 2) }},@{N='PercentFree'; E={[math]::Round((($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size) * 100), 2) }}}"
At line:1 char:277
+ ... - .FreeSpace) / .Size) * 100), 2) }},@{N='PercentFree'; E={[math]::Round(((.Free ...
+                    ~
You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.
At line:1 char:278
+ ...  .FreeSpace) / .Size) * 100), 2) }},@{N='PercentFree'; E={[math]::Round(((.FreeS ...
+                    ~~~~~
Unexpected token '.Size' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:277
+ ... - .FreeSpace) / .Size) * 100), 2) }},@{N='PercentFree'; E={[math]::Round(((.Free ...
+                    ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At line:1 char:238
+ ... ercentUsed'; E={[math]::Round((((.Size - .FreeSpace) / .Size) * 100), 2) }},@{N= ...
+                    ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At line:1 char:294
+ ... Size) * 100), 2) }},@{N='PercentFree'; E={[math]::Round(((.FreeSpace / .Size) *  ...
+                    ~
The hash literal was incomplete.
At line:1 char:3
+ & {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter 'DriveType = 3' |select PSComp ...
+   ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At line:1 char:294
+ ... Size) * 100), 2) }},@{N='PercentFree'; E={[math]::Round(((.FreeSpace / .Size) *  ...
+                    ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:296
+ ... ze) * 100), 2) }},@{N='PercentFree'; E={[math]::Round(((.FreeSpace / .Size) * 10 ...
+                    ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:297
+ ... e) * 100), 2) }},@{N='PercentFree'; E={[math]::Round(((.FreeSpace / .Size) * 100 ...
+                    ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:370
+ ... ) * 100), 2) }}}
+                    ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ok, I'll edit the question with some examples. thanks

Comment: Your 3rd example line was broken twice, it worked then here unchanged  in a cmd session, To not have the first powershell session consume the `$_` you will have to escape the `$` with a backtick `\`` --> `\`$` then it works also. To get a table insert `|Format-Table -auto` in front of the last curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to start working on:

```
GWMI Win32_LogicalDisk |
    % {
        "DeviceID:  $($_.DeviceID)"
        "FreeSpace: $($_.FreeSpace / 1GB)GB"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great! But how do we get disk labels on there?

Comment: @bluethundr check the edit.  In the future, you can use `(GWMI Win32_LogicalDisk) | GM` to see all the different members of the object you can call/utilize

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode your command, CMD don't like those long strings with pipelines:

```
$command = 'Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceID,VolumeName,@{N="SizeGB";E={[Math]::Round($_.Size /1gb,1)}},@{N="FreeSpaceGB";E={[Math]::Round($_.FreeSpace /1gb,1)}}'
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```